# AngularJS - PHP ошибка при отправке массива на сервер

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs

Делаю простое приложение "to do list" на Angular. При нажатии кнопки "Save all changes" данные ТАКОГО вида должны отправится на "app.php" для последующей записи на текстовый файл:

```
$scope.notes = [
    {id:1, aDate:'12.08.15', aTime:"12.00",  aNote:"Cleaning" },
    {id:2, aDate:'13.08.15', aTime:"12.00",  aNote:"My secret mission" },
    {id:3, aDate:'14.08.15', aTime:"12.00",  aNote:"Go to the pub" },
    {id:4, aDate:'14.08.15', aTime:"12.00",  aNote:"Rock'n'roll party" },
    {id:5, aDate:'14.08.15', aTime:"12.00",  aNote:"Swimming pool" },
    {id:6, aDate:'14.08.15', aTime:"12.00",  aNote:"Garbage day" },
];
```

Кнопка отправки:

```
<button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="sendArray()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-saved"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Save all changes</button>
```

Функция отправки массива:

```
$scope.sendArray = function() {
      alert($scope.notes); 
      var data='notes='+JSON.stringify($scope.notes);
      alert(data); 
      $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "app.php",
                        data: {data: JSON.stringify($scope.notes)},
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function(responseText){            
                          //$('.results').html(responseText); 
                           $('.resultsHandler').html(responseText);
                          },   
                          error:  function(xhr, str){
                                alert('Возникла ошибка: ' + xhr.responseCode);
                            }
                      });       
}
```

"app.php":

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors',1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    $data = json_decode($_POST['data'], TRUE);
    print_r ($data);
?>
```

При отправке сообщения на сервер, он callback-ом выдает алерт с ошибкой (никаких больше ошибок браузер не выдает):

> "undefined"

Во вкладке консоли network браузера гугл хром выводит сообщение, пришедшее на "app.php":

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [aDate] => 12.08.15
            [aTime] => 12.00
            [aNote] => Cleaning
            [$$hashKey] => object:3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [aDate] => 13.08.15
            [aTime] => 12.00
            [aNote] => My secret mission
            [$$hashKey] => object:4
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [aDate] => 14.08.15
            [aTime] => 12.00
            [aNote] => Go to the pub
            [$$hashKey] => object:5
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [aDate] => 14.08.15
            [aTime] => 12.00
            [aNote] => Rock'n'roll party
            [$$hashKey] => object:6
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [aDate] => 14.08.15
            [aTime] => 12.00
            [aNote] => Swimming pool
            [$$hashKey] => object:7
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [aDate] => 14.08.15
            [aTime] => 12.00
            [aNote] => Garbage day
            [$$hashKey] => object:8
        )

)
```

Как отправить этот массив объектов ангуларом и получить сервером грамотно и правильно?

Прошу объяснить подробно, а не строчкой куска кода.

Comment: А зачем вам `notes=` в `var data='notes='+JSON.stringify($scope.notes);`?

Comment: Нашел в интернете в ответах на похожий вопрос. Тут ещё только что увидел, что я два раза в строку перевожу. Это тоже наверное ошибка

Comment: Так-с, я немного не понял оказывается. Я подумал вы потом эту `data` используете, а она у вас здесь вообще лишняя. Я не сразу сообразил, что "Во вкладке консоли" это ответ сервера был. Смотрите на `dataType: "json"` - вы ожидаете ответ в виде json, а получаете текстом, потому и ошибка.

Comment: Вспомнил, для чего я ввел ''var data': чтобы посмотреть сообщение перед отправкой в алерте. Я удалил dataType: "json" и успешно получил ответ от сервера, как вы и  сказали, спасибо вам большое.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ANGULAR**: В Angular ничего не нужно "переводить" в `json`. Angular нативно работает с `json`. Просто отправляем запросы и оставляем всю работу серверу.

**PHP**: При получении используем `json_decode()`, если нужно, при при отправке `json_encode()`.

Принять в php и конвертировать в объект:

```
 $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
 $obj = json_decode($json);
```

Отправить из php обратно, например массив результатов:

```
 $arResult = array('data' => array(), 'status' => 'success');
 header('Content-type: application/json, charset: utf-8;');
 die(json_encode($arResult);
```

[PHP: JavaScript Object Notation](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.json.php)

Answer (score 0):

Как уже отвечено в комментариях, нужно использовать либо `JSON.stringify` либо `dataType: "json"`, но не оба способа сразу